# Finding duration of an uploaded video

Tags: asp.net, video

Is there any method for **finding the duration of an uploaded video** without running any exe (ffmpeg.exe) in asp.net? If so any one please suggest a method which can handle a heavy traffic site...

Answer (score 0):

You could force a user to upload a video with ID3 tags, and use the [Ultra id3 library](http://home.fuse.net/honnert/UltraID3Lib/)